# How to convert between function forms of single frequency signals

Tags: signal-analysis, analog

I have an equation x(t) = (3+4j)*e^(j*8*pi*t)+(3-4j)*e^(-j*8*pi*t) and am trying to convert between this and shifted sines and cosines. I'm attempting mash this through euler's formula and got a 10 for the peak amplitude. Omega is 8*pi, but I'm struggling with the finding the phase shifts for the sine and cosine and the amplitudes on the individual sines/cosines: A*cos(2*pi*f*t)+B*sin(2*pi*f*t).

Is this making sense? Can anyone point me in the right direction? Please and thank you!!

Comment: This is a special case equation.  Hint:  

$$ 3 + 4j = r e^{j\theta} $$

$$ 3 - 4j = r e^{-j\theta} $$

You should now be able to find $x(t)$ as a cosine expression.  Then use the angle addition formula from there.  Also, check out:

https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/1238.php

Comment: Note: 

$$ \cos( \theta ) = 3/5 $$
$$ \sin( \theta ) = 4/5 $$

Answer (score 0):

Easier yet.

$$
\begin{aligned}
 ( 3 + 4j ) e^{j\rho} + ( 3 - 4j ) e^{-j\rho} 
&= 3 ( e^{j\rho} + e^{-j\rho} ) + 4j( e^{j\rho} - e^{-j\rho} ) \\
&= 3(2 \cos(\rho)) + 4j( 2j\sin(\rho)) \\
&= 6 \cos(\rho) - 8 \sin(\rho)
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Cedron- thanks for your comment. This makes sense. The phase shifted angle would then be 53 deg, if I did that right...?

Comment: @Braimp985 Degrees???!!  'Spose that's 'bout right.  Cough, cough, ahem, you see that $\pi$ ya got there?